# Ngrok (compiled for Arm5) crash on android: can't find core dump files!

Tags: networking, shell, command-line

I downloaded Ngrok which I want to install on a old HTC Hero [the project is to transform the phone in a ipcam, reachable behind a NAT network], so I chose the version compiled for Arm5. You can find the executable here: https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.17_linux_arm_v5.zip

Now, I tried to launch it on Hero and on a Nexus 5 with Lollipop, but I got a "Segmentation fault" error. The developer of Ngrok ask me the core dump, but even if I set the ulimit to unlimited, I cannot find nothing in tombstones folder.
Can someone help me? For example trying the Ngrok on you phone and tell me 1) if gives the "segmentation fault" error; 2) providing me the core dump; 3) tell me why I cannot find the core dump files...

To execute Ngrok on android you have to put it ind /data/ folder, then assign executable permissions (chmod x+ ngrok OR chmod 555 ngrok), lastly execute it with ./ngrok

Thanks in advance,
J.